# Why do I not have a widget button on my phone?

Tags: home-screen, app-widgets, android-go

I have a Cricket phone and it is called U319AA. For some reason, when I hold down on my phone's home screen, the only buttons that pop up are home settings and wallpapers. This is a picture of my phone showing that when I press my home screen, there is no widget button and just settings and wallpaper.

[image]

I looked it up on Google and nothing on there helped me. I see that other phones have a widget button and I do not. This is another phone showing that I have done everything right but still can not find it.

[image]

I was concerned and I don't know if it's common and if all phones are supposed to have it or if some phones are supposed to not have it. I was trying to look for ways to get my widget button and I cannot find one. I'm hoping that someone can answer my question and help me.

Comment: Your phone is running Android 11 Go -> no widget support.